# Attribute error in python while trying to sign in

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using python (with selenium webdriver) to sign into yahoo.

Below is the code:

```
import unittest
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#Set Selenium firefox browser object
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

#Navigate to desired page
browser.get( 'https://www.yahoo.com/' )

try:
    element = browser.find_element_by_title( 'Sign In' )
except NoSuchElementException:
    self.fail( "found: %s" % 'Sign In' )
```

Below is the error I see:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_title( 'Sign In' ) 
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_title'
```

Any suggestions how to fix this error?

Comment: Looking at the manual for Selenium, there doesn't appear to be a find_element_by_title: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

Comment: when I tried using the ID, i still got following error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_username"}'

Any suggestions what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find_element_by_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_link_text) instead:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')
>>> element = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')
>>> element
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x1087fc5d0>
```

Comment: wow, it worked. Thanks alecxe. I have few questions regarding your code. what are these two lines?
element
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x1087fc5d0>

Comment: Also, while waiting for the response, I used selenium IDE to record all the steps involved with login and few actions after that and exported it to python -webdriver. I ran the code using python and I still got similar error as above. Below is what I see:

Comment: File "Zuora_subscription_python.py", line 19, in test_zuora_subscription_python
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").clear()
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_username"}' ; Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/h_/2szqh_217cj9klts6wnynd2h0000gn/T/tmpKngTDP/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9470)

Comment: I feel like "driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").clear()" is a very common command to use and for some reason it doenst work. For eg: some example codes that are available online are now working in my terminal. i wonder if I should be updating by webdrive (not sure what the issue is?)

Comment: In the above comment, I meant "some example codes that are available online are NOT working"